# My npm is out of date and I can't update it. How can I fix this?

Tags: node.js

I have had node and npm on my system for a while, but I haven't used them in a while and they seem to be broken.

Today I would like to get back to it and while trying to install yeoman, I got a message that "Your npm version is outdated." and advice to run `npm install -g npm`.

So I did that and got a lot more errors:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! node v4.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.mailmap
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.mailmap'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.mailmap']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.mailmap' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.npmignore'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.npmignore']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.npmignore' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Dan/npm-debug.log
```

I then tried this too

```
// ♥ unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.mailmap'
unlink: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.mailmap: Permission denied
```

Honestly, I can't remember whether I installed node with Homebrew or what else is on this thing. I think at some point I installed a node version manager but I could be wrong. Also, I always get nervous following instructions that say to use sudo. I can never remember which instructions to use sudo I'm supposed to not follow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo`.

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 1):

All set. I just followed [these instructions](http://www.johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/) from John Papa and it's working now.